# How to make my frontend's axios request wait long enough for a 2 minute response from nodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a React frontend that uses axios within a generator. I've added timeout of 0 in both the instance and the request itself just to be sure as I've read that 0 means there's no timing out. I also tried a 600000 timeout value.

```
// REACT / REDUX SAGA
axios.defaults.timeout = 0;
const response = yield axios.post('/iteminfo/', {
          data
        }, { timeout: 0 });
const itemInfo = response.data;
```

On my nginx / node server with express I have it requesting from another server, data that takes a long time to gather. It takes 1 minute and 20 seconds approximately.
I added 10 minutes of timeout to the node app to try to address this.

```
// NODE / EXPRESS SERVER
app.timeout = 1000 * 60 * 10; // 10 minutes

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`${portalStatus} NodeJS Listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

```
// SERVER TO SERVER REQUEST
axios.defaults.timeout = 1000 * 60 * 10; // 10 minutes
axios.post(baseURL2 + 'itemgather_api.php', qs.stringify(req.body))
.then(function (response) {
  console.log('Successfully gathered item...', response.data);
  res.json(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  handleError(error);
  res.status(400).json({error:error});
});
```

Looking at the backend PM2 logs I can confirm that the axios request from my server requesting the long data from another server had been resolved. But when it comes to pushing that data back as a response for my frontend there's something that goes wrong.

My frontend's axios POST request leads to this error after only 1 minute :

```
Error: Request failed with status code 504
    at e.exports (2.9443c470.chunk.js:1)
    at e.exports (2.9443c470.chunk.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onreadystatechange (2.9443c470.chunk.js:1)
```

My thinking is that it is the frontend that's timing out, not the backend, and it closes the connection after 1 minute, can anyone help me address this please?

I already set both frontend and backend's timeout to be longer based on some stackoverflow answers so I can't figure out what else I'm missing.